# Is it allowed to use same parameter in the embedded "Command" query and a stored procedure in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My report have two data sources: it is a "Command" SQL query embedded in the report, and a stored procedure in the database. They both have a single parameter of the same type (Number in Crystal Reports, and in stored procedure it is declared as int), and Crystal shows them as one parameter.

Both procedures simply return the value I pass to them as an output.

The data sources are linked using this output parameter, in the report I simply show the result of both Command and stored procedure.

In designer everything is fine, but when I try to call the report print programmatically (using C#), most times everything is fine, but sometimes (once in 3-10 launches) it fails with one of the two errors:

```
Exception verifying database : 
Error in File tmpDAC3 5908_9464_{7E6D1CAA-1968-41E1-A58D-5C5CF204B45D}.rpt:
The specified value type is different to the current value type.
```

or

```
The types of the parameter field and parameter field current values are not compatible.
```

If I remove links between the Command and stored procedure, there are not fails. If I remove the values from report, there are no fails. If I remove the parameter from either Command of stored procedure, there are no fails. If I add other columns that are not related to the parameter and link the data sources using them, it still sometimes fails with same errors, I suspect that a combination of these conditions lead to such strange behavior, but did not find anything like that in the internet.

I use Crystal Reports 2008 designer and 13.0.20.2399 runtime

1) Am I doing something that is not allowed?
2) Is there any other way to pass same parameter to both Command and a stored procedure?

Comment: How do you call the execution of the Store Procedure in your report?

Comment: I add a procedure through Database Expert, then in Field Explorer, expend the procedure, right click on a required field returned from the procedure, Insert to Report. When a report is created, I pass all the parameter values to Crystal and expect that it calls the procedure itself now sure how exactly. I can attach an example of failing report if the explanation was not what you expected or it can help in some other way

Comment: can you show us the Command code and the SP code too?

Comment: Command and the stored procedure for the simplest scenario when I managed to reproduce the issue:
Command: single parameter, @SystemID,
`select
{?@SystemID} SystemIDParameter`. 
Stored procedure: 
`create PROCEDURE [dbo].[simpleProcedureWithIntParameter]
  @SystemID int
AS
BEGIN
  select
 @SystemID SystemIDParameter
END`.
I used SQL Server Express 2008 R2 for debugging, but the original issue reproduced also on SQL Server Express 2014

Comment: can you also display the C# code?

Comment: I will do it later, the day after tomorrow probably. It is rather large project, but most of work there is parsing input/output. I'll try to leave only relevant content